# Arabic font is too small on some devices

Tags: android, fonts, textview, arabic, samsung-mobile

I have a problem with rendering of arabic text on Android. I am using [library](https://github.com/eeVoskos/RobotoViews) for Roboto font.

Let's say I have an arabic text set in `TextView`, font size is set to `20sp`. My problem is that the arabic text is **too small on all of our Samsung devices** (SII, SIII, SIV, Note I, Note II, etc.). **The text is rendered properly on Nexus devices** (and maybe even on other devices).

How it is possible that the height of the arabic text differs depending on the used device even if I am using custom font? Any idea?

Comment: have u create diffrent layout folder like layuot-hdpi,layuot-ldpi,layuot-mdpi and so on.....

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar Why? My problem is that a TextView with the same text and same textSize attribut is rendered differently on Samsung and Non-Samsung devices.

Comment: how many layout folder do u have in project

Comment: layout, layout-ar, layout-sw600dp and layout-ar-sw600dp...Don't know why are you asking for this. This is not relevant IMO.